# Is it possible to attach Qt creator to a running gdb session?

Tags: debugging, gdb, qt-creator

I have a running gdb session, that is attached to a running process.

I managed to get the point of interest with gdb, but it would be nice to continue the debugging from the GUI of Qt Creator.

Detaching gdb and re-attaching from Qt Creator is an option, but it is a slow process because of the number of shared libraries involved.

Since gdb has all of these loaded and it is stopped at the right location, it would be nice to use Qt Creator as a GUI for the running gdb session. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

They have some mechanisms (almost all IDE have): [qt creator doc](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-operating-modes.html#attaching-to-running-applications). But usually, you have to manage some extensions for a comfort debugging, what is not acceptable sometimes.

Anyway, there are many GUI for gdb server.